# Поиск значения или как исключить дублирование данных в БД?

Tags: delphi, база-данных

Здравствуйте!

Как осуществить поиск определенного значения в БД? К примеру, с клиентского приложения пришло сообщение, содержащее имя, контактные данные и некоторую информацию. Имя и контактные данные записываются в таблицу1, а имя и информация - в таблицу2. Две таблицы связаны по имени. Но нужно, чтобы, если такое имя есть в таблице1, то его не добавлять, а добавлять лишь информацию и имя в таблицу2. По типу исключения дублирования записей в столбце (дублирование строки)... Я вот не знаю, как сделать эту проверку?. Я пробовал через ADOQuery получить все значения столбца (вообще, возможно ли такое?), к примеру:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT name FROM table1');
ADOQuery1.Active:=True;
```

Чтобы потом по содержимому запроса проверить, если такое имя, но почему-то возвращается одно значение: это значение первой строки.

Как поступить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно... так почему нельзя

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE field1=:value1, ...');
ADOQuery1.Active:=True; // опять Active?? Ой подозрительно это..
```

**UPD**
Мне всё равно непонятно. У вас есть конкретное значение, с которым вы сравниваете? Так почему это правило сравнения нельзя сформулировать в WHERE? Active подозрительно по той же причине, по которой это было подозрительно с сокетами.

Так почему вы не можете сделать запрос типа

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE username=:value1, ...');
// ...set value1 to parameters...
ADOQuery1.Active:=True; // ??
// проверить есть ли что-то в результатах
```

А потом взять и выполнить INSERT, если ничего не было найдено?
Разумеется, у вас также в базе должен быть UNIQUES CONSTRAINT по username. Без него ни в коем случае нельзя обойтись - **это единственный надёжный способ избежать дублирования данных**.

**UPD2**
Если бы я реализовывал ADOQuery, то я бы со страшным грохотом кидал бы ошибку, в случае, когда у меня спрашивали данные, которых у меня нет. Чёрт возьми, ну почему вы не слушаете? :) Надо не сравнивать Felds[0].asstring, который не существует, если записей нет, а проверять-таки, есть ли строка или нет; проверяйте

```
if ADOQuery1.EOF then begin 
    {создаём-таки нового пользователя}
end
```

Comment: Мне нужно получить все записи столбца name чтоб потом сравнить с полученным значением... А тут получается что в ADOQuery будет содержаться, в вашем случае определенное значение, а в моем тока значение столбца первой строки, т.е первая запись... Почему Active подозрительно?...

Comment: uniques - уникальный, ну у меня стоит в базе что оно ключевое, и повтор не допускается... Т.к если я вручную ввожу он выводит ошибку при добавлении такой же записи... Так, т. е если не будет найдено значение то ADOQuery.Fields[0].asstring будет содержать пустую строку? Верно?...

Comment: Зачем вы запрашиваете имя? Оно вам нужно? Почему не спросить ID? ADOQuery должен иметь возможность проверить, есть ли сейчас данные в result set'е или нет. Не надо пытаться ничего ни с чем сравнивать.

Comment: Сейчас по вашему ответу я спросил Id, в бд он у меня счетчик, а name - ключевое, для связи... Теперь ADOQuery.Fields[0].asstring будет содержать пустую строку, если нет Id при нужном нам name и наоборот, так?..

Comment: см. UPD2

Comment: @cy6erGn0m...)))Спасибо вам за помощь;) В принципе и с ADOQuery.Fields[0].asstring,работает, он выдает пустую строку, я проверял) Спасибо вам) Вы единственный кто мучается со мной по этим темам;)

Comment: Пусть даже так. Всё равно не стоит испытывать судьбу. Что же до меня, то я иногда отвечаю, потому что у меня ваши вопросы вызывают неподдельное удивление :)

Comment: Можно вопрос "почему??")))

Comment: Используйте инфу из моего профиля для связи - там и обсудим, чтобы не сорить тут ;)

Answer (score 0):

Поддерживаю вариант с WHERE и ID.
Но если вам надо принципиально, тогда после ADOQuery1.Active:=True сделайте переход на нужную строку с помощью ADOQuery1.Locate('бла-бла-бла')